# EmberJS: Access to component html from within the component js

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to access from within the component JS file the inner contents of the component initialization. I essentially would like to have access to yield.

For example let's say I have an hbs with this template:

```
{{#my-component}}
  <span>bla bla {{foo}}</span>
{{/my-component}}
```

Then I want in my component to access that span above like in the example below, where in the theInnerHtml I want to get what was inside the initialized component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didInsertElement() {
    let theInnerHtml = this.get('innerHTML'); // "<span>bla bla {{foo}}</span>"
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code where actually you want to do? sample example

Comment: `this.$().html()`, not that I would recommend it, what is your use case? Why do you need access to it?

Comment: @Kitler That returns to me the contents of my component template. Not the what was inside the body of the component when initialized. We're trying to use the Kendoui widget set in our application and in places we need it to use it as a template for the widget

Comment: @valanto can you give me an example of a kendo ui component that you want to integrate into your app? I don't see a reason to get the yielded value

Comment: @Kitler For example their list view component takes data and a template and renders you a list of items using that template. i would like to specify that template as the "yield" part of my component definition like in my example "<span>bla bla {{foo}}</span>" and then get that in my component js and initialize my kendo component.

Comment: Jump on [slack](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can jQuery, which is already built into Ember, to get a jQuery object for the element you're looking for,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didInsertElement() {
    let theInnerHtml = this.$('span').html();
  }
});
```

or you can just use Ember Component's element property:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_element

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didInsertElement() {
    let theInnerHtml = this.element;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not using yield inside my component template so I don't have it there. Is there a way to just take it in directly in the component js file?

Comment: I never use yield in mine either - but I still use these when I need to access the component's DOM.

Comment: This returns the dom of the component as you correctly mention. I want to get the html inside the block when it was initialized in my example "<span>bla bla {{foo}}</span>"

Comment: Ahh, apologies! I see what you mean now. Can't help you there. It seems like an unusual thing to need access to, but that's your business :)

Comment: Quite an obvious thing to want actually. Somethings in html cant be bound like if you were drawing something in a canvas. You would need access to that canvas. You cant grab by ID ro class because there might be multiple of them on the page.

Comment: Very old answer :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this would be to make a sort of `kendo-component` component with the sole purpose of initialising the kendo component.

It would have a simple `{{yield}}` for a template allowing us to pick up the yielded content via `this.$().html();` which in reality is the template that will be passed to the kendo ui component.